# Suggestions for beginner in Robotics

Tags: robotics

I am beginner in Robotics.I want to make serious start from scratch with interest but confused from where to start.So can anyone give some suggestions for 1.As a beginner in robotics ,**are there some simple and basic robots or circuit designs which I can make by myself in the home**(so that I can gain practical knowledge of robots)? 2.or should I first read books (can anyone suggest some good reference **book names,articles ,links,video series**)?

Comment: @Benjoyo sir , what software tools are must required on my laptop.? Are they available on internet for downloading and free?Can u send me link?

Comment: You'll find everything here http://www.arduino.cc

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest starting with Arduino. There are Arduino boards in all sizes and with a ton of addons (sensors, motors, wifi/bluetooth etc.) that can be assembled relatively easy. You can build your own or even use prebuilt Arduino robots. And they are also relatively easy to program (C/C++ dialect). Also, there's a bunch of tutorials and books on the internet.

Comment: Not a bad idea, whatever one thinks about the Arduino extensions, the same hardware can later be used for programs written from scratch, too, so it's not a bad place to start.